# after Fork(), how to stay in parent process?

Tags: c, linux, unix, pthreads

I have an example here:

```
int runcmd(char *cmd)
{
  char* argv[MAX_ARGS];
  pid_t child_pid;
  int child_status;

  parsecmd(cmd,argv);
  child_pid = fork();
  if(child_pid == 0) {
    /* This is done by the child process. */

    execvp(argv[0], argv);

    /* If execvp returns, it must have failed. */

    printf("Unknown command\n");
    exit(0);
  }
  else {
     /* This is run by the parent.  Wait for the child
        to terminate. */

     do {
       pid_t tpid = wait(&child_status);
       if(tpid != child_pid) process_terminated(tpid);
     } while(tpid != child_pid);

     return child_status;
  }
}
```

This one is a classic example of fork()
After fork(), the control goes to child process.
How can I keep in parent process, do stuffs. Instead of jumping to child immediately?

Thank you

Comment: I think you misunderstand. `fork()` returns to BOTH the child and parent processes. The `if` section is executed in the child process, the `else` part runs in the parent process.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The child will always be the child. The parent will always be the parent. `fork()` **creates a new process**, and each runs separately. If you want to do something in the parent then do it in the parent.

Answer (score 0):

Once you call `fork`, the scheduler decides whether the parent or child get to run first. They may even run in parallel: multiple CPUs and cores are common nowadays.

If there is some action that the parent has to take before the child runs, then you should 
place that action before the `fork`. Otherwise the parent and child have to synchronize somehow.

Answer (score 0):

When fork() is executed, two separate OS processes are created. So the OS scheduler will then decide when each gets run, you cannot decide that.